# DIV ul li boxes behaving badly

Tags: html, css

Please look at this image (https://ibb.co/CmgqTRN), my div boxes are behaving badly, when there are more than 4 in my loop. I have been trying to add float:left here and there, but it havnt really helped me. So I cant spot the error here.

The boxes should go from top-left in reading direction like below (depending on screen size)

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Can someone help me with this?

CSS:

```
div.contentText {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container ul{
  overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.container ul li{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  width:20%;  
  background: white;
  margin :20px 0px 20px 55px; 
  border:1px solid #273239;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container ul li:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container ul li .bottom{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #303841;    
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color:white;
}

.bottom_read{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #303841;    
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color:white;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul>

        <a class="read-more" href=\"read-question.php?dpid="<?php echo $getknowmedId;?>" title=\"Læs mere\">
            <li>
                <div class="bottom">
                    Spørgsmål oprettet d. <?php echo date("d-m-Y H:m:s", strtotime($getknowmedEntrydate));?><br />
                    Af: <?php echo $getknowmedUserentryname;?>
                </div>
                <div class="contentText"><p><b><?php echo $getknowmedHeadline;?></b></p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </a>
      <?php }
    } else {echo "Either no questions are created or search result returns empty..";}?>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Full LOOP code, didnt think it would matter. :) Moved the , that didnt help.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['SearchIt'])) {
      $SearchIt = $_POST['SearchIt'];
    } else {
      $SearchIt = Null;
    }
    if(isset($SearchIt)) {
      $getknowledge = $conn->prepare("SELECT k.knowmed_id, k.knowmed_headline, k.knowmed_content, k.knowmed_created_by, k.entry_date, k.knowmed_active, u.Fname FROM knowmed_main AS k INNER JOIN users AS u ON k.knowmed_created_by = u.userid WHERE MATCH (k.knowmed_content) AGAINST ('*".$SearchIt."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY k.knowmed_id DESC");
    } else {
      $getknowledge = $conn->prepare("SELECT k.knowmed_id, k.knowmed_headline, k.knowmed_content, k.knowmed_created_by, k.entry_date, k.knowmed_active, u.Fname FROM knowmed_main AS k INNER JOIN users AS u ON k.knowmed_created_by = u.userid ORDER BY k.knowmed_id DESC");
    }
    $getknowledge->execute();
    $resultknowledge = $getknowledge->get_result();
    $getknowledge->close();

    if ($resultknowledge->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $resultknowledge->fetch_assoc()) {
        $getknowmedId = $row["knowmed_id"];
        $getknowmedHeadline = $row["knowmed_headline"];
        $getknowmedContent = $row["knowmed_content"];
        $getknowmedUserentry = $row["knowmed_created_by"];
        $getknowmedEntrydate = $row["entry_date"];        
        $getknowmedUserentryname = $row["Fname"];?>
    
        
            <li>
                <div class="bottom">
                    Spørgsmål oprettet d. <?php echo date("d-m-Y H:m:s", strtotime($getknowmedEntrydate));?><br />
                    Af: <?php echo $getknowmedUserentryname;?>
                </div>
                <div class="contentText"><p><b><a class="read-more" href="read-question.php?dpid=<?php echo $getknowmedId;?>" title="Læs mere"><?php echo $getknowmedHeadline;?></a></b></p>
                </div>
            </li>
      <?php }
    } else {echo "Either no questions are created or search result returns empty..";}?>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put the rendered source code here as the browser receives it?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete chunk of your code?

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs from your php loop. You have a else tag but i dont see the if condition. Check your php please.

Comment: I pu in the whole code with the loop.

Comment: What happens if you display items of the same size? Do you have gaps then as well?

Comment: It was the height. Thank you. Didnt see just whom got first. But accepted below as the answer, since I also moved <a>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not have the `<a>` element as direct child from the `<ul>`

As the documentation about [`<ul>` says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) the allowed content is

> Permitted content: Zero or more `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements.

You should change your markup to

```
<div class="container">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more" ...>
                <div class="bottom">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">...</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

More complete example as follows:

```css
div.contentText {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container ul{
  overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.container ul li{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  width:20%;  
  background: white;
  margin :20px 0px 20px 55px; 
  border:1px solid #273239;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container ul li:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container ul li .bottom{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #303841;    
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color:white;
}

.bottom_read{
  font: normal 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #303841;    
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
             <a class="read-more">
                <div class="bottom">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="contentText">Dolor sit amet</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaikLowrey true the `if` is missing but also the output in `else` should be wrapped by `<li>` element because it is still inside the `<ul>`

Comment: I tried moving <a>, it didnt help.

Comment: @MauiRiis yes, one more problem is that your boxes have different heights depending on how "big" the content is: see this example => https://jsfiddle.net/7zw2qf03/ there are many different ways to solve that

Comment: Oki, ty. I'll try look into that.